# A possible axiomatic characterization of the set of divisors of a perfect number

Tags: nt.number-theory, perfect-numbers

Define a *pro-perfect set* $S$ to be a finite set of positive integers satisfying the  following three properties:

1. $1\in S$.
2. $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in S}n^{-1}\in S$
3. There exists a unique permutation $\pi$ of $S$ of order $2$ such that $$\frac{1}{\vert S\vert}\sum_{n\in S}n\pi(n)\in S.$$

**Question 1**: Is any pro-perfect set necessarily the set of divisors of a perfect number?

**Question 2**: Does every pro-perfect set  necessarily contain $2$?

*Edit 1*: it might help to consider the more general notion of *$k$-pro-perfect set* such that property 3 is replaced by

3' : There exists a (not necessarily unique) permutation $\pi$ of order $k$ such that $$\frac{1}{\vert S\vert}\sum_{n\in S}\prod_{\ell=0}^{k-1}\pi^{\circ \ell}(n)\in S.$$

*Edit 2*: Let $s_{\text{inv}}$ denote the quantity $$s_{\text{inv}}:=\frac{1}{\vert S\vert}\sum_{n\in S}n\pi(n),$$ one gets the following equivalence: $$\forall n\in S, \quad n\mid s_{inv}\;\Longleftrightarrow\;\pi:n\mapsto\frac{s_{\text{inv}}}{n}.$$

Edit 3: let $s_{rec}$ denote $\sum_{s\in S}n^{-1}$ and suppose the $m$ first elements of $S$ when arranged in increasing order form a geometric progression with constant ratio $q$. Then $s_{rec}\geq\frac{1-q^{-m}}{1-q^{-1}}$. The latter is less than $2$ as $q\geq 2$. Moreover $s_{rec}\leq\frac{\vert S\vert(1-q^{-m)}}{m(1-q^{-1})}<\frac{2\vert S\vert}{m}$.

Comment: Is $\{1,2,3,6\}$ pro-perfect?  Of course $\sum n^{-1} = 2$ but I did not find a permutation of order $2$ for rule 2.

Comment: Take $\sigma(n)=6/n$.

Comment: I misread $\sigma(n)$ as the sum of divisors of $n$... This is a question about perfect numbers after all...

Comment: Similarly, $\tau$ is not be understood as the divisor function :-)

Comment: Are there any cases with $s_{\mathrm{inv}} \ne \max S$

Comment: I think the implication is actually an equivalence, since $\pi$ is a permutation of a set of positive integers. Hence $s_{inv}/n$ is an integer and for all $n\in S, n\mid s_{inv}$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: if $s_{inv}\neq\max S$ then $n\pi(n)$ is not a constant. If think this is not compatible with the required property of unicity but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

$$
S = \{1,2,3,12,18,36\}
$$
then
$$
\sum_{k \in S}\frac{1}{k} = 2 \in S
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k \in S} k \pi(k) = 36 \in S
$$
when $\pi$ is the permutation of $S$ that reverses the order, while
$$
\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k \in S} k \pi(k) > 36
$$
for any other permutation $\pi$.

Uniqueness of the minimizing permutation is from [Hardy-Littlewood-Polya rearrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).

Comment: Indeed. So the axioms I gave are not sufficient.

Comment: Maybe one should require that $S$ contains all divisors of $s_{inv}$.

Comment: So I suggest that a pro-perfect set fulfilling the stronger condition above be called maximal. Do you think there may be maximal pro-perfect sets not corresponding to sets of divisors of a perfect number?

Comment: Another one, still not all divisors... $[1, 2, 5, 9, 10, 18, 45, 90]$.

Answer (score 2):

Note:  $\sigma(n) = 3n$ for $n=120$.
[$\sigma$ the sum of the divisors]

Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 30, 40, 60, 120\}$ be the set of all positive divisors of $120$.  Then $|S| = 16$, 
$$
\sum_{k \in S}\frac{1}{k} = 3 \in S
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{16}\sum_{k \in S} k\pi(k) = 120 \in S
$$
where $\pi$ is the permutation that reverses the order, and
$$
\frac{1}{16}\sum_{k \in S} k\pi(k) > 120
$$
for all other permutations.

---

Note: if $S$ is the set of all divisors of some positive integer $m$, then
$$
\sum_{k \in S} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{\sigma(m)}{m}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{k \in S} k\pi(k) = m
$$
where $\pi$ is the permutation that reverses $S$, and
$$
\frac{1}{|S|}\sum_{k \in S} k\pi(k) > m
$$
for all other permutations.

Comment: I wish I could accept this answer too!

Comment: So maybe a maximal pro-perfect set is the set of divisors of a $k$-multiperfect number, with $k$ possibly greater than $2$. In that case, $k$ would be equal to what I denote as $s_{rec}$.